# is there any API exists for Moodle?

Tags: api, moodle

I want to create a customized front end for Moodle. Does anyone know that from where I can get API for this? or any other help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Edit: I have written on, moodle theme modification which we did at http://www.iank.it/category/e-learning/
for http://www.edupristine.com/ca ]

It will be very tiresome to create a complete new frontend for moodle, I would suggest choose a theme which looks closest to what you want and then start modifying it.

You will have to understand moodle's database and tables structure and also Moodle database Manipulation API.

After this you can straight jump into tinkering the moodle code and understand its core functions wherever required.
You would also benefit from many plugins available if you modify the moodle frontend instead of creating one.

Answer (score 8):

You can install and then call Moodle's "webservices":

- http://cipcnet.insa-lyon.fr/Members/ppollet/public/moodlews/
- [moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=67947](http://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=67947)

Also, call Moodle from MOSS:

- [fraserelder.blogspot.com/2009/03/moodle-integration-solution.html](http://fraserelder.blogspot.com/2009/03/moodle-integration-solution.html)

or the new Moodle 2 Web Services:

- [docs.moodle.org/en/Development:Web_services](http://docs.moodle.org/en/Development:Web_services)
- [moodle.org/mod/forum/view.php?id=6971](http://moodle.org/mod/forum/view.php?id=6971)

Moodle can integrate well with Google Sites/Apps ,Joomla ,Drupal and Wordpress (SSO, Web Services...)

Comment: Not everything in moodle is available in web services. It is not possible to create an entire new frontend based on that.

Answer (score 7):

The Moodle core is well documented on their [website](http://docs.moodle.org/en/Development:Developer_documentation).  Try checking through those first.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the PHP cross reference API for moodle 1.9.9 at http://xref.moodle.org/nav.html?_functions/index.html