# Moodle Interface for .net

Tags: c#, moodle

My company is planning to setup Moodle for internal & external training courses. Our training team has a lot of training material - mostly in MS Word/HTML/PDF/PPT slides format that needs to be converted into courses in Moodle.

It is becoming too much of work to manually create new course/lesson and add text/images from existing material into it.

I am asked to check if this can be automated. So here I am exploring the option of injecting the data directly into Moodle database (in our case it is MySQL) using a WinForm application.

Is there any better way/API/Interface to Moodle that can be used via .net WinForm application? I am particularly interested into adding new category/Course/Lesson at the moment.

I already had a look at http://moodle2003wp.codeplex.com/ [SharePoint Web Parts for Moodle] and [is there any API exists for Moodle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009196/is-there-any-api-exists-for-moodle) [is there any API exists for Moodle?]

[SharePoint Web Parts for Moodle] has a data assess layer for Moodle but looks like it's read only - it can't write stuff back into Moodle.

Any pointer will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anyone is interested and/or having the same problem as me:

I found this web service that can be used to access Moodle database: http://cipcnet.insa-lyon.fr/Members/ppollet/public/moodlews/

It's doesn't have access to everything (e.g. lessons) on Moodle but still quite useful and can be used with-in a .net application.

Comment: I know it's the same web service mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009196/is-there-any-api-exists-for-moodle but just wanted to confirm that it is useful towards the solution I am looking at.

Comment: How did you eventually make it work in .net ? Any more info ?